# Preserve space between two element, even when <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/> applied on top

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I am converting HTML --> FO .
I need to preserve space between two

```html
<var>
```

tag, which are child of

```html
<span>
```

when I put below in my xsl:

xsl:strip-space elements="*" --> Removes all the spaces around

xsl:preserve-space elements="span" --> Preserve all redundant spaces also in other data scenario, which are not necessarily in between  tag.

I need to preserve space which are only between **var**.

HTML:

```html
<span style="font-size:11pt;font-family:&quot;&quot;">DATED: <var name="DATE"/> DAY of <var name="DAY"/> <var name="YEAR"/></span>
```

I am losing white space between

```html
<var name="DAY"/>LOST_space<var name="YEAR"/>
```

XSL:

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<!--xsl:preserve-space elements="span"/-->

<xsl:template match="span">
    <fo:inline height="0pt" font-family="abc" white-space-collapse="false" font-size="11pt" text-decoration="inherit">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:inline>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="var">
    <xsl:variable name="defaultSystemValue">_________</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="$defaultSystemValue"/>

</xsl:template>
```

Output:

```html
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<fo:inline height="0pt" font-family="abc" white-space-collapse="false" font-size="11pt" text-decoration="inherit" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">DATED: _________ DAY of __________________</fo:inline>
```

Expectation:
DATED: _________ DAY of _________ _________

Current Output:
DATED: _________ DAY of __________________

Comment: There is no finer grained control with `xsl:strip-space/preserve-space` as the one you have found. So I guess you will need to preserve space on `span` elements and for those not containing `var` (e.g. `span[not(var)]`) you might want to apply templates that remove the white space from text nodes that you don't want.

Answer (score 0):

Since you know that it can happen, work around it in your XSLT by adding the space when required.

You could add an `xsl:if` in the template that you already have.  Since you're using XSLT 2.0 and `xsl:next-match` will find templates in the current stylesheet (unlike XSLT 1.0), you have the option of making a separate template for the second `var`:

```
<xsl:template match="var[preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::var]]">
  <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
  <xsl:next-match />
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks Tony,
But here data between var is user's data which can or can not have space. 
My problem is to preserve white-space only when there is possibility that  strip-space will omit that white-space data, which is happening in this case. 
I think it is not suggestable to append a white-space between var.

Comment: If there is non-white-space text between the `var`, then the predicate will be false and the template won't be used.  Similarly if you used `<xsl:if test="preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::var]">` in your current template. (If you stop using the `xsl:strip-space`, then this answer won't be any use to you.)

Comment: Right, But if user had not put space between var, I will end up adding a space between var in output. Do you suggest adding more check after this ?

Comment: Sorry, yes.  That possibility wasn't obvious (to me) from your question.  There's nothing more to check because the XSLT won't be able to tell whether or not there was a space between `var` in the original.  The next idea would be to preserve space within `span` and have a template/templates that do the right thing with white-space-only text nodes depending on their context.

Comment: I just adjusted the place of your code and made a little modification(normalize-space(.)=''), And it started working, Pls check the below code and pls share your opinion on this.
<xsl:template match="var">
 <xsl:if test="preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::text()][normalize-space(.)='']">
  <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
 </xsl:if>
  <xsl:variable name="defaultSystemValue">_________</xsl:variable>
  <xsl:value-of select="$defaultSystemValue"/>
 </xsl:template>